# How to rsync via gateway ssh?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I want to rsync my local files with a backup which I have on a server which allows access from where I am right now only via a gateway. So I came up with the following

```
rsync -avz -r --stats --progress -e "ssh gateway.dot.com ssh server.dot.com:/home/myname/documents/" /home/myname/documents
```

and there is some communication going on as all the files get listed but at the summary at the end reveals that there was actually no file trasfer at all.

```
Number of files: 270889
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 70343212868 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 7596005
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 7613770
Total bytes received: 17764

sent 7613770 bytes  received 17764 bytes  50707.87 bytes/sec
total size is 70343212868  speedup is 9217.44
```

Ideas?

Comment: Maybe all files are already in sync and there is no transfer necessary???

Comment: In fact they are not. It absolutely looks like it but there are hundreds of changes and several newly generated files in these folders and subfolders.

Comment: Just to clarify - the _newer_ files are on the server and I want to get them on my local machine.

Comment: many thx to user crayzeewulf: the answer is rsync -avz -r --stats --progress -e "ssh gateway.dot.com ssh" server.dot.com:/home/myname/documents/ /home/myname/documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Shouldn't the `rsync` command be `rsync ... -e "ssh the.gateway ssh" /local/dir/ the.remote.server:/remote/dir/`?
2. <del>The message **`speedup is 9217.44`** shows that the transfer is `9217` times optimized, that's to say the files between the two hosts are almost (if not already) sync'd.</del>

### UPDATE:

#2 is not correct. See [crayzeewulf's answer](https://superuser.com/a/570101/209415) for more explanation. The speedup value misled me to understand that it worked.

Comment: Thx for the answer and the comments! #2: The files are not in sync, there are hundreds of files that were changed and some were added. #1: in this case I get "bash: the.remote.server: command not found..."

Comment: @clarkw, you were correct originally. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/570101/209415).

Comment: Oh yeah, I see it also now. Sorry for the confusion guys and thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @crayzeewulf: Thanks. The speedup values misled me. Updated my answer to not confuse more people. :)

Answer (score 9):

I think item#1 in [clarkw's answer](https://superuser.com/a/569805/209415) is correct. If you use `...-e "ssh gateway.dot.com ssh server.dot.com:/home/myname/documents/"`, the corresponding rsync command has a source directory but no destination directory. In this case, according to the rsync manual:

```
Usages with just one SRC arg and no DEST arg will list the source 
files instead of copying.
```

This is exactly what is going on. You can check this by providing garbage as the `-e` argument. For example:

```
rsync -avz --stats -e 'suq maballs' /tmp
```

This command will work just fine. It will list everything under `/tmp` and display nice stats at the end:

```
Number of files: 28
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 182 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 955
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 998
Total bytes received: 26

sent 998 bytes  received 26 bytes  2048.00 bytes/sec
total size is 182  speedup is 0.18
```

Notice that no files are transferred here just as in your example. You need to modify your original command:

```
rsync -avz -r --stats --progress \
    -e "ssh gateway.dot.com ssh server.dot.com:/home/myname/documents/" \
    /home/myname/documents
```

to:

```
rsync -avz -r --stats --progress \
    -e "ssh gateway.dot.com ssh" \
    server.dot.com:/home/myname/documents/ \
    /home/myname/documents
```

Of course, replace `gateway.dot.com` and `server.dot.com` with the appropriate host names.

Comment: WOW THX! That works perfect :) I would never have gotten that right without help. Just as a remark, there is one " too much in your solution-command.

Comment: Glad to see that it worked. @clarkw had it right the first time. Also, thanks for reporting my mistake. I have fixed it. Please [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if you are satisfied.